# Setting silent mode at a specific date and time

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I'd like to set the ringer mode to silent for specific events in the future. It should only happen if a checkbox in the preferences is checked. I know that I have to update the manifest for the permissions and also that I can set the ringer mode with something like this:

```
if (getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(PREFS_KEY_SILENTOPTION, false)) {
   AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
   audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}
```

But how can I set (and reset) it for a space of time in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). It allows you to "schedule your application to be run at some point in the future".

Comment: Here's a tutorial I found that explains how to use the AlarmManager: http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129